# VSTS Azure App Service Deploy release task doesn't update files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, msdeploy, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my release definition, I have a step to deploy Azure web app service.
The step is finished without any errors, however, the application files inside the wwroot folder aren't changed.
Below are the logs for this step:

```
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6519687Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6520505Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6521823Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6522364Z ##[debug]=> True
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6522960Z ##[debug]Result: True
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6523283Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6532729Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6532941Z Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6533434Z Description  : Update Azure WebApp Services On Windows, Web App On Linux with built-in images or docker containers, ASP.NET, .NET Core, PHP, Python or Node based Web applications, Function Apps, Mobile Apps, Api applications, Web Jobs using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6533758Z Version      : 3.3.47
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6533900Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6534147Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2018-06-04T11:33:58.6534361Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3700194Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=D:\a
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3728077Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3733912Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3743052Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f_SERVICEPRINCIPALID
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3744991Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f_SERVICEPRINCIPALKEY
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3747384Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f_TENANTID
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3748988Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3752177Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3753927Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3762167Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3764454Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUILTINLINUXPACKAGE
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3766013Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONNECTEDSERVICENAME
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3769223Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DEPLOYTOSLOTFLAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3770780Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DOCKERIMAGETAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3772243Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DOCKERREPOSITORYACCESS
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3773874Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_EXCLUDEFILESFROMAPPDATAFLAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3776019Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GENERATEWEBCONFIG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3778404Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_IMAGESOURCE
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3782399Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PACKAGE
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3785149Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEADDITIONALFILESFLAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3787205Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_RENAMEFILESFLAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3788675Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SCRIPTPATH
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3792890Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SETPARAMETERSFILE
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3794770Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TAKEAPPOFFLINEFLAG
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3796033Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_USEWEBDEPLOY
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3797768Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBAPPKIND
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3799792Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBAPPNAME
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3801422Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLTRANSFORMATION
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3802688Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLVARIABLESUBSTITUTION
2018-06-04T11:33:59.3813905Z ##[debug]loaded 27
2018-06-04T11:33:59.4137921Z ##[debug]agent.proxyurl=undefined
2018-06-04T11:33:59.4139193Z ##[debug]VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS=undefined
2018-06-04T11:33:59.4139704Z ##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6358043Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.3.47\task.json
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6361018Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.3.47\task.json
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6362477Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6498166Z ##[debug]ConnectedServiceName=82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6501539Z ##[debug]WebAppName=XXXXXAPP
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6502672Z ##[debug]WebAppKind=app
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6504365Z ##[debug]DeployToSlotFlag=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6505866Z ##[debug]VirtualApplication=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6508534Z ##[debug]Package=D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6510245Z ##[debug]GenerateWebConfig=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6510679Z ##[debug]WebConfigParameters=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6512305Z ##[debug]XmlTransformation=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6513464Z ##[debug]JSONFiles=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6514797Z ##[debug]XmlVariableSubstitution=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6516893Z ##[debug]UseWebDeploy=true
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6518387Z ##[debug]TakeAppOfflineFlag=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6519647Z ##[debug]RenameFilesFlag=true
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6520311Z ##[debug]AdditionalArguments=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6520595Z ##[debug]ScriptType=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6520882Z ##[debug]InlineScript=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6521833Z ##[debug]ScriptPath=D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6522120Z ##[debug]DockerNamespace=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6522450Z ##[debug]AppSettings=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6524040Z ##[debug]ImageSource=Registry
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6524356Z ##[debug]StartupCommand=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6524701Z ##[debug]WebAppUri=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6524980Z ##[debug]ConfigurationSettings=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6527601Z ##[debug]RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6535376Z ##[debug]SetParametersFile=D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.SetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6541101Z ##[debug]ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag=false
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6541333Z ##[debug]AdditionalArguments=null
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6550903Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f data subscriptionid = GUID
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6551349Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f data subscriptionname = Pay-As-You-Go
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6553543Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f auth param serviceprincipalid = ***
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6555106Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f auth param serviceprincipalkey = ***
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6555509Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f data environmentAuthorityUrl = https://login.windows.net/
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6557905Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f auth param tenantid = ***
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6559149Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f=https://management.azure.com/
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6559716Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f data environment = AzureCloud
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6560423Z ##[debug]82e35813-117a-4528-8bdc-11c81d0ff34f data activeDirectoryServiceEndpointResourceId = https://management.core.windows.net/
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6596130Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'XXXXXAPP'
2018-06-04T11:33:59.6634436Z ##[debug][POST]https://login.windows.net/***/oauth2/token/
2018-06-04T11:33:59.8009164Z ##[debug][GET]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resources?$filter=resourceType EQ 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' AND name EQ 'XXXXXAPP'&api-version=2016-07-01
2018-06-04T11:33:59.9987632Z ##[debug]Resource Group: XXXXXAPP_RG
2018-06-04T11:34:00.0004240Z ##[debug][POST]https://login.windows.net/***/oauth2/token/
2018-06-04T11:34:00.1632760Z ##[debug][POST]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/XXXXXAPP_RG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/XXXXXAPP/publishxml?api-version=2016-08-01
2018-06-04T11:34:00.6677707Z ##[debug][GET]http://XXXXXAPP.azurewebsites.net
2018-06-04T11:34:00.9414300Z ##[debug]App Service status Code: '301'. Status Message: 'Moved Permanently'
2018-06-04T11:34:00.9425111Z ##[debug][POST]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/XXXXXAPP_RG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/XXXXXAPP/config/publishingcredentials/list?api-version=2016-08-01
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4434508Z ##[debug]set AZURE_APP_SERVICE_KUDU_production_PASSWORD=********
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4438825Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=AZURE_APP_SERVICE_KUDU_production_PASSWORD;issecret=true;]***
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4443201Z ##[debug]Finding files matching input: D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4451380Z ##[debug]File Tranformation not enabled
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4452315Z ##[debug]Performing the deployment of webapp.
2018-06-04T11:34:01.4461073Z ##[debug][POST]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/XXXXXAPP_RG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/XXXXXAPP/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2016-08-01
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8391847Z ##[debug]Rename locked files is already enabled in App Service
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8847713Z ##[debug]SetParametersFile=D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.SetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8850767Z ##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.SetParameters.xml = D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.SetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8851284Z ##[debug]build.sourcesDirectory=undefined
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8851635Z ##[debug]system.defaultWorkingDirectory=D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8852006Z ##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: D:\a\r1\a = D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8852331Z ##[debug]SetParametersFilepath supplied :true
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8852652Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:34:01.8853824Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2282477Z ##[debug]Is the package an msdeploy package : true
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2284526Z ##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2284827Z ##[debug]Constructed msDeploy comamnd line arguments
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2285471Z ##[debug]appservice.msdeployretrycount=undefined
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2289929Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=D:\a\r1\a
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2296111Z ##[debug]the argument string is:
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2297010Z ##[debug] -verb:sync -source:package="'D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip'" -dest:auto,ComputerName="'https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP'",UserName="'$XXXXXAPP'",Password="'***'",AuthType="'Basic'" -setParam:name="'IIS Web Application Name'",value="'XXXXXAPP'" -setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml  -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2297695Z ##[debug]converting the argument string into an array of arguments
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2300188Z ##[debug]the array of arguments is:
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2300675Z ##[debug]arg#0: -verb:sync
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2301040Z ##[debug]arg#1: -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2334815Z ##[debug]arg#2: -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2338746Z ##[debug]arg#3: -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2339153Z ##[debug]arg#4: -setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2339861Z ##[debug]arg#5: -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2340493Z ##[debug]arg#6: -userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2340789Z ##[debug]which 'msdeploy'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2816090Z ##[debug]found: 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2816460Z ##[debug]which 'msdeploy'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2818602Z ##[debug]found: 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2822414Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe arg: ["-verb:sync","-source:package='D:\\a\\r1\\a\\XXXXX_Build\\XXXXX\\XXXXX.zip'","-dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic'","-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP'","-setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml","-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule","-userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1"]
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2823546Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe arg: ["-verb:sync","-source:package='D:\\a\\r1\\a\\XXXXX_Build\\XXXXX\\XXXXX.zip'","-dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic'","-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP'","-setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml","-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule","-userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1"]
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2828281Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2828862Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2829408Z ##[debug]arguments:
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2829692Z ##[debug]arguments:
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2829997Z ##[debug]   -verb:sync
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2834934Z ##[debug]   -verb:sync
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2846041Z ##[debug]   -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2846989Z ##[debug]   -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2847664Z ##[debug]   -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2848357Z ##[debug]   -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2848923Z ##[debug]   -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2849502Z ##[debug]   -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP'
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2850030Z ##[debug]   -setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2850362Z ##[debug]   -setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2850908Z ##[debug]   -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2851263Z ##[debug]   -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2851635Z ##[debug]   -userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2852040Z ##[debug]   -userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:02.2872121Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\XXXXX_Build\XXXXX\XXXXX.zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXAPP',UserName='$XXXXXAPP',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='XXXXXAPP' -setParamFile=tempSetParameters.xml -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_e9a6b698-6440-443e-a398-c358fe7b1c29_release_4_304_2030_1
2018-06-04T11:34:05.0759932Z Info: Using ID '1463afeb-f397-49f5-9860-b8c3f3592a8c' for connections to the remote server.
2018-06-04T11:34:07.8631955Z Info: Adding ACLs for path (XXXXXAPP)
2018-06-04T11:34:07.8632751Z Info: Adding ACLs for path (XXXXXAPP)
2018-06-04T11:34:07.8898015Z Info: Using ID '6754ac43-0b17-4852-b068-be1040bbc09c' for connections to the remote server.
2018-06-04T11:34:08.9107837Z Info: Adding ACLs for path (XXXXXAPP)
2018-06-04T11:34:08.9108873Z Info: Adding ACLs for path (XXXXXAPP)
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0365187Z Total changes: 4 (0 added, 0 deleted, 4 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0987232Z ##[debug]rc:0
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0987527Z ##[debug]rc:0
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0987908Z ##[debug]success:true
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0988126Z ##[debug]success:true
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0995926Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0996686Z ##[debug]rm -rf D:\a\r1\a\tempSetParameters.xml
2018-06-04T11:34:09.0998262Z ##[debug]removing file
2018-06-04T11:34:09.1026443Z ##[debug][GET]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/XXXXXAPP_RG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/XXXXXAPP/config/web?api-version=2016-08-01
2018-06-04T11:34:09.8306183Z ##[debug]Skipped updating the SCM value. Value: VSTSRM
2018-06-04T11:34:09.8323287Z ##[debug][GET]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/providers/microsoft.insights/components?$filter=InstrumentationKey eq 'bbf98e17-8af5-495d-a013-9e14966f8b24'&api-version=2015-05-01
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3035682Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseUri=vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/304
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3036084Z ##[debug]Build.BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/151
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3037014Z ##[debug]Release.DefinitionName=XXXXX_Release
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3037317Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseName=Release-204
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3037980Z ##[debug]Build.BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/151
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3038676Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseWebUrl=https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59/_release?releaseId=304&_a=release-summary
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3039189Z ##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3039661Z ##[debug]System.TeamProjectId=1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3040063Z ##[debug]build.buildId=151
2018-06-04T11:34:10.3049416Z ##[debug][PUT]https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/XXXXXAPP_RG/providers/microsoft.insights/components/XXXXXAPP/Annotations?api-version=2015-05-01
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1136052Z ##[debug]addReleaseAnnotation. Data : {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","content-length":"353","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","expires":"-1","x-ms-request-id":"195f5969-0b0c-4da3-bec2-323d858cba7c","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains","x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes":"1199","server":"Microsoft-IIS/8.5","x-powered-by":"ASP.NET","x-ms-correlation-request-id":"e3f218c9-cf92-43f9-a8a0-638343cd7177","x-ms-routing-request-id":"NORTHCENTRALUS:20180604T113411Z:e3f218c9-cf92-43f9-a8a0-638343cd7177","date":"Mon, 04 Jun 2018 11:34:10 GMT","connection":"close"},"body":[{"AnnotationName":"XXXXX_Release - Release-204","Id":"1df1e49f-6eca-4c77-87a1-b8dc22e180c0","Category":"Text","Properties":"{\"Label\":\"Success\",\"Deployment Uri\":\"https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59/_release?releaseId=304&_a=release-summary\"}","EventTime":"2018-06-04T11:34:10.303+00:00","RelatedAnnotation":null}]}
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1138848Z Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : XXXXXAPP
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1142961Z ##[debug]build.sourceVersionAuthor=undefined
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1143466Z ##[debug]build.requestedfor=Sergey  
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1143817Z ##[debug]build.buildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/151
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1144142Z ##[debug]release.releaseUri=vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/304
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1144511Z ##[debug]build.buildId=151
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1145581Z ##[debug]release.releaseId=304
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1146548Z ##[debug]build.buildNumber=R1.4_20180529
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1147174Z ##[debug]release.releaseName=Release-204
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1152875Z ##[debug]system.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1153437Z ##[debug]system.teamProjectId=1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1153914Z ##[debug]build.sourceVersion=939
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1154283Z ##[debug]build.repository.name=XXXXX Application
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1155329Z ##[debug]build.repository.provider=TfsVersionControl
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1155740Z ##[debug]build.buildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/151
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1156109Z ##[debug]release.releaseUri=vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/304
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1156447Z ##[debug]build.buildId=151
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1157196Z ##[debug]release.releaseId=304
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1157610Z ##[debug]build.buildNumber=R1.4_20180529
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1158002Z ##[debug]release.releaseName=Release-204
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1158414Z ##[debug]system.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1158848Z ##[debug]system.teamProjectId=1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1159230Z ##[debug]build.sourceVersion=939
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1159674Z ##[debug]build.repository.name=XXXXX Application
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1160241Z ##[debug]build.repository.provider=TfsVersionControl
2018-06-04T11:34:11.1165194Z ##[debug][PUT]https://$XXXXXAPP:***@XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3041528112051114
2018-06-04T11:34:12.7504296Z ##[debug]updateDeployment. Data: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","content-length":"933","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","expires":"-1","server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","x-ms-request-id":"9ad3446c-7bad-4d11-a827-d4f74de4c5e9","x-aspnet-version":"4.0.30319","x-powered-by":"ASP.NET","set-cookie":["ARRAffinity=8a8d8dd9156bbc837a024bd4b077d8299002a88a7be8967241d8478205e5f430;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net"],"date":"Mon, 04 Jun 2018 11:34:12 GMT","connection":"close"},"body":{"id":"3041528112051114","status":4,"status_text":null,"author_email":null,"author":"Sergey  ","deployer":"VSTS","message":"{\"type\":\"Deployment\",\"commitId\":\"939\",\"buildId\":\"151\",\"releaseId\":\"304\",\"buildNumber\":\"R1.4_20180529\",\"releaseName\":\"Release-204\",\"repoProvider\":\"TfsVersionControl\",\"repoName\":\"XXXXX Application\",\"collectionUrl\":\"https://YYYYY.visualstudio.com/\",\"teamProject\":\"1591217f-c442-4ac1-8afd-072c15f20d59\",\"slotName\":\"production\"}","progress":null,"received_time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","start_time":"2018-06-04T11:34:12.546166Z","end_time":"2018-06-04T11:34:12.546166Z","last_success_end_time":null,"complete":false,"active":true,"is_temp":false,"is_readonly":false,"url":"https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3041528112051114","log_url":"https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3041528112051114/log","site_name":null}}
2018-06-04T11:34:12.7506684Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://XXXXXAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3041528112051114
2018-06-04T11:34:12.7647383Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

I've added the step to clean the wwwroot folder content (using Kudu REST API and COMMAND verb).
After completion, the directory looks like:

[image]

After clean, the deploy is performed correctly.

I am wondering why application redeploy (update) doesn't change the necessary files.

Comment: What's the type of your web application? And what if you use the 
Azure App Service Deploy task version 4.* (Preview) instead?

Comment: App type is "Web App". I've changed the task version from 3* to 4* (Preview), now the app type is "Web App on Windows" and it correctly updates the files. Thanks for pointing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the Azure App Service Deploy task with 4.* (preview) version, and select your App Service type correspondingly.

[image]